# Keras-Model doesn't train properly, when changing the shape of Output-Layer (Keras)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to predict the classes of images.
The classes are stored in an Label-Array: `array([0., 0., 1., ..., 2., 2., 0.], dtype=float32)`
I have 3 classes (0,1 and 2)

My Model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential([
Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
       input_shape=(64, 64 ,3)),
MaxPooling2D(),
Dropout(0.5),
Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
MaxPooling2D(),
Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
MaxPooling2D(),
Dropout(0.5),
Flatten(),
Dense(512, activation='relu'),
Dense(256),
Dense(3, activation = 'relu')
])
```

When I use the shape of 3 for the last Dense-Layer, the Loss and Accuracy don't change at all during training.
When I increase the shape to 5 for the last Dense-Layer then the Training is working fine.
Why doesn't it work with shape of three? I have three classes after all.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
                    epochs=num_epochs,
                    validation_data=(val_images, val_labels),
                    callbacks = [tensorboard])
```

I also tested an sgd optimizer with the same results

Comment: ReLU does not produce logits, you should use a linear activation at the output, not ReLU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to do multiclass classification but you are using `relu` as the output layer activation function. For multiclass classification you should use `softmax` in the last layer and keep a number of neurons in that layer equal to the number of classes you want to classify.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your anwer. I changed the last Layer to: Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'), but the loss and accuracy still won't change during Training.

Comment: @zyros That's because `softmax` goes hand in hand with `categorical_crossentropy` loss, not its sparse version you are using here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using softmax activation for last layer and categorical_crossentropy solved my problem

Comment: @zyros Oops, I hadn't noticed the loss function you had. I'm glad it works fine now!